# SQL SERVER PIVOT TABLE One Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table for e.g.

```
  PAY    STAFF    AMOUNT       TAX
   1       40     10.00        1.5
   1       40     20.00        3.0
   1       40     15.00        2.0
```

I want output table like this for e.g.

```
PAY  STAFF AMOUNT1 TAX1    AMOUNT2 TAX2   AMOUNT3    TAX3
 1    40     10    1.5       20   3.0      15.00     2.0
```

How do I get this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a dynamic crosstab. Read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) by Jeff Moden for reference:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/864de/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
      Pay
    , Staff
'
SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), RN) + ' THEN Amount END) AS [Amount' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), RN) + ' THEN Tax END) AS [Tax' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), RN) + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM YourTable
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM(
    SELECT *, RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM YourTable
)t
GROUP BY Pay, Staff
ORDER BY Pay, Staff'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```